# Windows 10 security regarding malicious zipped files

Tags: windows-10, html, zip, malware, 7-zip

Is there any possibility of malware infection in Windows 10 for the following three situations,

a) When you download a zipped file, but do not use it (you do not open it)?  and

b) When you only open a zipped file (with 7-zip), but do not extract/run its content?  and

c) When you download a ".html" file, but do not open it?

Thank you

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question. Also, it really sounds like there's context missing. Why are you asking these questions? What are you hoping to learn or accomplish that leads you to ask these? Knowing rhe broader context may help us give you an answer more directly appropriate to your specific needs.

Answer (score 2):

The answers to all your questions are typically "No" however...

If you download a zip or archive file in general, then the format is a container that certain applications can understand and may take action on.  Of course, these could include Explorer (displaying a different icon, thumbnail based on content, etc), an archive application, security products that unpack archive files to scan the content.  These all run in a session and in the context of a user, maybe the security product is running as local system for example. In any case, any of these processes that inspect the file for their own reasons could have a security vulnerability with the way they parse the file that could be exploited by a crafted file.

Same for an HTML file, applications that understand/handle this file type/format could fall foul of a crafted file that exploits a vulnerability in it. This extends to all 3 of your questions really.

So in summary highly unlikely but it is possible.